# Why does ckeditor right-click context menu not work in basic package?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to figure out why ckeditor's context menu (with Paste and other options) doesn't appear when I right-click in the document body of ckeditor in an app I'm developing.

To debug, I tried [downloading](http://file:///C:/Users/jensenv/Downloads/ckeditor_4.6.2_standard/ckeditor/samples/index.html) both the 'Basic' and 'Standard' packages (4.6.2) and running the 'Sample'.

The same issue exists in the Basic package (browser's context menu appears instead of ckeditor's) but it WORKS in the Standard package (ckeditor's context menu appears).

Can anyone explain to me what the root cause of this is? I checked the plugins folder in the Standard distribution to see if there was anything obvious, like a 'contextmenu' plugin, but didn't see anything that stood out. I also checked samples/js/samples.js but didn't see anything obvious there, either. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard and Full packages contain the [contextmenu](http://ckeditor.com/addon/contextmenu) plugin which provides the editor's context menu to use instead of the browser's native menu in place. Basic package doesn't contain this plugin. You can check this with the [online builder](http://ckeditor.com/builder).

Comment: Thank you! I'm curious though: why, when I look in the 'plugins' folder (of the standard package) do I not see the contextmenu plugin there? This is true of other plugins as well... they seem to be 'built-in' somehow, without being in the plugins folder. Can anyone explain this? How can I, at a glance, see ALL plugins that a given ckeditor currently has 'built-in'?

Comment: The Basic, Standard and Full packages contain their plugins inside 'ckeditor.js', that's why you don't see folders of them in 'plugins' folder. If you want to see their plugins, go to the [online builder](http://ckeditor.com/builder) and choose your preset at the top. You will then see below the selected plugins for this preset (you can add or remove plugins of course)...

Comment: .... At the bottom of the page, you'll see the Download button. If you click 'Optimized', the 'Download' button will integrate all plugins inside 'ckeditor.js', just like the precompiled packages. If you click 'Source (Big N’Slow)', the 'Download' button will put all plugins in their own folder inside 'plugins' folder. If you want the contextmenu plugin in the Basic package, just add it through the online builder to the Basic preset. If it has any dependencies, the online builder will also add the necessary plugins.

Comment: Thanks Wizard. However, I'm not seeing the Optimized button you're referring to. I'm using http://ckeditor.com/download

Comment: Click the 'Online Builder' button which is in the 'Customize' area to the right of the page. This will take you to the online builder, where you start with a preset and customize it.